# Apply Changes Button Grayed out: Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-instant-run

I have set up my project's `minSdkVersion` as 15 and enabled `Instant Run` .
I have deployed the app in my device running on API 21 
But the "Apply Changes" button is grayed out.When I hover over the button it says "No Active 'App' launch" although I am running the app in my device at that time .

Comment: open task manager and check if adb.exe is running or not. if not, restart the process from this path: your sdk> platform-tools> adb.exe

Answer (score 1):

According to [the guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html#set-up-ir), you also need to choose the **debug** build variant.

> To start using Instant Run, you also need to change the build variant
>   to a debug version of your app and deploy it to a target device
>   running Android 5.0 (API level 21) or higher.

Comment: Your answer is outdated.. Your guide now says: _Apply Changes uses capabilities in the Android JVMTI implementation that are supported on devices running Android 8.0 (API level 26) or higher._

Answer (score 1):

By default, Instant Run is disable when you first install Android Studio. So you need to enable it by following this path :- **File/Settings/Build, Execution, Deployment/InstantRun** and checked the **Enable InstantRun** check box.

Answer (score -1):

click Run icon to run your project ,android the icon will be highlight.