# Disabled "apply changes" on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, button

**Problem**: 
Some of you guys who worked with Android Studio knows that we have to click "apply changes" if we want to apply the changes for our application. 
My problem now is that this button is disabled/grayed out so that I can not even click on it. 
Here is what I mean:
[image: Here is what I mean]

**What I tried so far**:
I tried the solutions of this links here but it did not worked, neither the "Invalidate Caches/Restart" nor "Sync Project with Gradle files":

- [Apply Changes Button Grayed out: Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43976751/apply-changes-button-grayed-out-android-studio)
- [Apply changes button in android studio is disabled(gray color)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48621461/apply-changes-button-in-android-studio-is-disabledgray-color?rq=1)

Does anyone of you guys know what else I can try to do?

Answer (score 21):

From [Android doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/#apply-changes) you can see :

> Apply Changes is only compatible with devices running **Android 8.0 (API level 26) or higher.**

Answer (score 6):

Change Build Variant to debug

View->Tool Windows-> Build Variants

Answer (score 3):

This is called instant feature of Android studio. That allow you apply change instead of running app again.
From [android doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/) you can see that.

**1. You must enable instant run to use it.**

> On Windows and Linux, click **File → Settings** In the
>   Settings/Preferences dialog, go to **Build, Execution, Deployment →
>   Instant Run.**

**2. Your app must be running in device**

> If you want take advantage of instant run, first run it by green play button (shift + F10). If your app is not running, instant run is disabled.

**3. You must have the SDK platform corresponding to the testing device installed to use instant run.**

> > Let's say you are testing your app on a device/emulator running marshmallow(6.0). You must have 6.0 SDK platform installed to use instant run on that test device.

Comment: Your linked doc now states _Apply Changes uses capabilities in the Android JVMTI implementation that are supported on devices running Android 8.0 (API level 26) or higher._

Answer (score 2):

Just build again. It works for me. [like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46GeY.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: nice, this helps